# Getting data from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This code is dbhelper class to get data from SQLite db in my system C: and db name School. Method getinformation is throwing error table does not exists. Can someone please help regarding the same. This code is dbhelper class to get data from SQLite db in my system C: and db name School. Method getinformation is throwing error table does not exists. Can someone please help regarding the same.
 This code is dbhelper class to get data from SQLite db in my system C: and db name School. Method getinformation is throwing error table does not exists. Can someone please help regarding the same.

```
    package com.example.rabin_pc.myproject;

    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
    import static android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.*;
    import static android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase;

    /**
     * Created by Rabin_PC on 14-Jul-17.
     */

    public class CollegeDBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static String DB_PATH;


        private static String DB_NAME="School.sqllite";

        private static final int DB_VERSION=1;

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
        private Context myContext=null;

        public CollegeDBHelper(Context context){

            super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
           // log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS" , "DATABASE OPENED");


        }

        public CollegeDBHelper(Context ctx,String databaseName)  {
            super(ctx, databaseName, null, DB_VERSION);
            DB_NAME = "School.db";
            this.myContext = ctx;
            //DATABASE_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath() ;
            DB_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Rabin_PC\\Documents\\";
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException
        {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if(dbExist){
                //do nothing - database already exist
            }else{
                //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
                //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try
                {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }
        private boolean checkDataBase()
        {       SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try
            {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

                 Log.e(TAG,myPath);
                checkDB = openDatabase(myPath, null, OPEN_READONLY);
            }catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                //database does't exist yet.
            }
            if(checkDB != null)
            {
                checkDB.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
        {
            //Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
            {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            //Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = openDatabase(myPath, null, OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        @Override
        public synchronized void close()
        {
            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();
            super.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {


                Cursor cursor;

                String[] projections = {CollegeContract.newCollegeContract.COLLEGE_NAME, CollegeContract.newCollegeContract.COLLEGE_ADDRESS};
              //  System.out.print("++++Before executing++++++++++++++ 4444444444444444");
                cursor = db.query(CollegeContract.newCollegeContract.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null);
               // System.out.print("++++Before executing++++++++++++++ 555555555555555");


                  return cursor;
        }



        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
```

---

Comment: `DB_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Rabin_PC\\Documents\\";` So, on your Android device you have a drive **`C:`**?!

Answer (score 0):

first of all create your table in `onCreate()` and you didn't called `createDataBase()` method and in `onUpgrade()` drop table and call onCreate method again and the `DB_NAME` is different you used two DB_NAME `School.sqllite` AND `School.db` may be because name its showing error  and there is no initialisation of `DATABASE_NAME`

I will give a basic SQLiteOpenHelper class

```
public class mySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static String DB_NAME="School.sqllite";


 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_COMMENTS + "( " + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
            + " text not null);";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```